# Read actual object from PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I am currently struggling with the typing of the PowerShell in C# when accessing the exchange-server. Basically, this is what I have:

```
Collection<PSObject> results;
using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create()) {
powershell.AddCommand("Get-Mailbox");
    runspace.Open();
    powershell.Runspace = runspace;
    results = powershell.Invoke();
}
```

Now I have a collection of `PSObject`, but I would like to have a collection of `Mailbox`-Objects.

How can I convert this?

In the TypeNames-property of each PSObject, there is an entry `Deserialized.Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Management.Mailbox`, which is pretty close to what I want: `Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Management.Mailbox`.

Answer (score 0):

There's going to be some loss of fidelity in the serialization/deserialization process. I don't think you'll be able to "re-hydrate" it back into the object it was serialized from.